How to write an azure function, with pdf upload , read and analyze through gen ai
I am very new to test an azure function. Here i am trying a function,in which i will upload some documents in pdf format, and ask gen Ai to analyze them and get valuable insights.
earlier, I was getting different error, but present i am getting None type error.
My code is:
import logging
import pathlib
import tempfile
import PyPDF2
import azure.functions as func
from langchain_groq import ChatGroq


app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
groq_api_key=" key"
@app.route(route="ingest", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def test(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        # Fetch the file from the form-data
        file = req.files.file('file')
        # Fetch GUID from form-data
        guid = req.form.get('guid') 
        if not guid and req.headers.get('Content-Type') == 'application/json':
            try:
                req_body = req.get_json()
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                guid = req_body.get('guid')
        if not guid:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "GUID is missing in the request.",
                status_code=400
            )
        
        suffix = pathlib.Path(file.filename).suffix
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=suffix) as temp:
            temp.write(file.read())
            temp_path = temp.name
        
        documents = []
        with open(temp_path, 'rb') as file:
            reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
            text = ''
            for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
                page = reader.pages[page_num]
                text += page.extract_text()
            documents.append(text)
        message = f"data: {documents}"
        # Join all document texts into a single string
        return func.HttpResponse(message)
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Info: Error Encountered. -- {e}", status_code=500)

 @app.route(route="risk_prediction")
def risk_prediction(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    documents=test(req)
    llm = ChatGroq(groq_api_key=groq_api_key,
                  model_name="llama3-70b-8192")
    result=''
    prompt='''Provide valuable insight on loan risk for applicants, by anlyzing the documents {documents}'''
    for doc in documents:
        messages = [
    (
        "system",prompt,
    ),
    ("human", f'''contract document is {doc} and anlysis of previous document is {result}, include previous findings with current data and update response''')]
    
        result =llm.invoke(messages).content
    
    return result

I tried it to test with post man.With get method but i am not getting any option to upload files in postman.
and following error is throwing:
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.risk_prediction. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I am very new to azure functions. I tried with a simple function, where string values are parameters and only once function is called, and working correctly.
but this one is not:
I tried url in postman:
http://localhost:7071/api/test
 http://localhost:7071/api/risk_prediction

second url is throwing error. first url is not doing anything.

Post full traceback so we can see exactly which line is erroring on


Exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

This error occurs when the object you are trying to iterate over has a value of None, because None is not iterable.

I tried it to test with post man.With get method but i am not getting any option to upload files in postman.

To send the file in Postman, choose Post method and paste the API/function URL http://localhost:7071/api/risk_prediction.

Navigate to Body, select form-data and choose file in key and you will be able to see select files option in the value section.



Click on select files and choose the pdf which needs to be analyzed.



Run the function:

Functions:

        risk_prediction:  http://localhost:7071/api/risk_prediction

        test:  http://localhost:7071/api/ingest

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-08-19T12:15:54.741Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-08-19T12:20:23.356Z] Executing 'Functions.test' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=25621f80-d4XXX87cbb1b)
[2024-08-19T12:20:23.444Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-08-19T12:20:23.526Z] Executed 'Functions.test' (Succeeded, Id=25621f80-d419-479c-XXXcbb1b, Duration=208ms)


yes i realized mistake. I was not loading files correctly
